# Как работает WPF на низком уровне?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Я не знаю, правильно ли я задаю вопрос, так я простой любитель .NET.

Я умею создавать GUI на WPF, но не понимаю, как он устроен под капотом. Знаю, что WPF написан на С++. Как такое возможно, что часть когда на одном языке, другая на другом? Как они взаимодействуют друг с другом? Может где-то можно посмотреть элементарный пример, как создать графику на C++ и затем ее использовать в .NET?

Comment: [Вот так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-architecture?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Знаю, что ссылки на сторонние источники тут не особо одобряют, но например [вот](https://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/) очень детально. А [вот тут](http://codingseason.blogspot.com/2012/09/wpf-architecture.html) довольно кратко, но тоже неплохо

Comment: DirectX там под капотом. Как вызвать код C++ библиотеки из C# кода, вам расскажет технология P/Invoke.